# How to set CFB-128 using Microsoft CryptoAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, aes, cryptoapi, mscapi

I am using `MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV` provider with `PROV_RSA_AES` provider type. I have selected `CALG_AES_128` block cipher algorithm with `CRYPT_MODE_CFB` cipher mode.  I would like to set `KP_MODE_BITS` key parameter to 128, but calling `CryptSetKeyParam()` by passing value greater than 64 always returns with NTE_BAD_DATA (0x80090005L).

How can I set CFB-128 using CryptoAPI? Thanks.